2-D scalene obtuse triangle trigonometry.
I am struggling with this trigonometry question:

I tried using the cosine law with angle DBC
$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos A$ but you need to know the measure of the angle.
In terms of the angle Φ, the length of DC would be $32 - 32 cosΦ$
From here onwards I'm not sure what to do. Is my method so far even the right method?
Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Firstly - this is not a "do my homework" site so I am not going to post a full answer but Secondly - you have shown some attempt, so... consider the angle $\theta + \phi$. You can work out the cosine of this angle and then get the length of AC. If you are not sure how to get the cosine of this angle, start by looking at how $\sin{\theta},\sin{\phi}$ are related and how $\cos{\theta}, \cos{\phi}$ are related.

Well, I know that sin(90 - θ) = cos θ, cos(90 - θ) = sin θ, sin(90 + θ) = cos θ, and cos(90 + θ) = - sin θ.
Is this what you are saying?

OK... I started with ADC being $180^{\circ}$ and so the cosines of the two angles at D must sum to $0$. With a bit of sine rule and cosine rule you can reduce the length of AC to the equation $2\times CD^2=48$. See if you can fill in the in-between steps.

How exactly would the sums of the cosines of the 2 angles equal to 0? Is there some kind of rule that I am not aware of?

It is basic trigonometric symmetry. I will post a complete solution if and when time permits.

Ah I see what you mean. In the graph of a cosine wave, -cos(pi - x) = cos x for all x, due to the "symmetry" around the line x = 90 degrees.

For the purposes of this answer, I am going to label the length of $AD$ as $d$, the length of $CD$ as $d$ (they are equal in the question), angle $ADC$ as $x$ and angle $BDC$ as $y$.
By the cosine rule:
$64=16+d^2-8d\cos{x}$ and so $\cos{x}=\frac{d^2-48}{8d}$
$16=16+d^2-8d\cos{y}$ and so $\cos{y}=\frac{d^2}{8d}$
Now, because $x+y=180^{\circ}$, $\cos{x}+\cos{y}=0$
So $\frac{d^2-48}{8d}+\frac{d^2}{8d}=0$
Which means $2d^2=48$ and therefore $d=2\sqrt{6}$ and the length of $AC$ is $2d=4\sqrt{6}$
Now for the rest:
Area of $\Delta ABC=\frac{1}{2}\times 8\times 4\sin{(\theta+\phi)}=16\sin{(\theta+\phi)}$
Area of $\Delta DBC=\frac{1}{2}\times 4\times 4\sin{\phi}=8\sin{\phi}$
The heights of the triangles are the same but AC is double the length of DC so Area of $\Delta ABC=2\times$ Area of $\Delta DBC$
Which means $16\sin({\theta+\phi})=2\times 8\sin{\phi}$
Therefore $\sin({\theta+\phi})=\sin{\phi}$
Two angles have the same sine if they sum to $180^{\circ}$ so $\theta+\phi+\phi=180^{\circ}$
And we are done.
